# Are we able to bypass MobileConnect 160 Character limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

We are doing an automation on sending text messages for the bounce emails. During our test, we only received 1 text message. However, when we generated the report, it said that it delivered 2 text messages with truncated content.

> Dear firstname lastname, the email that we recently sent you has bounced.
>   Please update your email at https://test12312.1234.org.12  [+44
>   character org name]

This message exceeds the 160 limit however we only receive 1 sms and report shows differently.

EDIT:

[image: Missing concatenate option]

Comment: One thing you can do is use Google Shortner to create bitly link for any URL which you are sending in SMS. This will reduce character count significantly.

Comment: @RohitMourya thank you for the great tip! I'm still wondering why we got only 1 sms when the report shows that we should receive 2 with concatenated content. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a message in Mobile Connect, there is an option to **Concatenate Message** in the Messages section; under the Outbound Message text area.
[image: Message Concatenate]
Enabling this will allow for >160 character messages to be sent; providing your region/aggregator allows for this.

If you are still having issues, speak with your Account Executive to ensure the Concatenate feature is enabled in your region.

Comment: Hi @cameronrobert - we dont see this option 'concatenate message' also, how will we know that this feature is enabled in your region. I live in singapore with +65 prefix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm in Australia with a +61 prefix. I would advise that you talk to your Account Exec or Success Agent to discuss what options your account has. You may not have access to it in Singapore - or it may just need to be activated by SFMC Support.

Comment: Thanks @cameronrobert! we'll take your advise raise a case for this. May I ask when you generate the report, are you seeing 1 concatenated message delivered or 2? In our case we receive 1 concatenated message and in the report it reflected as 2 messages delivered.

Comment: A bit of a long read, but see the [SMS/GSM documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service) on Wikipedia for some general details on how SMSs work. They are sent as 160 character payloads, however **some** phones/operators allow messages to be "connected" together (Concatenated). Either way, you will be charged 1 SMS per 160 characters*; note that this changes based on characters/From Header, etc. See the section on [**Message size**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Message_size) on the Wiki page.

Comment: so the mobile connect report might be breaking it up per 160 chars and the service provider still sends it as 1 sms. I'll read up more on this. Thanks for the help!